# How to send packets via a pptp vpn tunnel?

Tags: networking, iptables, ip

I'm trying to send certain port traffic through my ppp0 interface it's a pptp vpn tunnel,

First, I'm using a wireless usb interface, I connect up to my access point, then I initiate my vpn, there is a connection but I do not channel all connexions through that, nor do I want to, so, say I want to channel all port 80 packets through my vpn (interface dev ppp0).

I first run:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 0xa
```

to mark the correct packets
then I add a table named vpn_table,
I then add

```
ip route add default dev ppp0 table vpn_table
```

when I do that traffic begins to dribble through the ppp0, but no pages load.
I supose I must have caused some sort of coflict, or the route I'm adding in vpn_table isn't quite right.

I'm not sure, I think I'm marking the packets correctly but I can't be sure of that either.

UPDATE: I think i've got part of the issue solved: running tcpdump -i ppp0 showed me that indeed there was outgoing requests via ppp0, now, there is never a response, and pages do not load with using that interface..i'm still missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this issue, I'll try and post precise instructions for other people:

```
ip address show:
```

vpn address is 192.191.145.5

some relevant info:

```
39: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 3
link/ppp 
inet 10.20.0.42 peer 10.20.0.1/32 scope global ppp0
```

ip route show table local
     local 10.20.0.42 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.20.0.42

additional commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
ip route add 10.20.0.1/32 dev ppp0 table vpn_table
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.20.0.42 dev ppp0 table vpn_table
ip route add 192.191.145.5 via 10.20.0.42 dev ppp0 table vpn_table
```

that is what is needed in the vpn table

this command

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.rp_filter=2 is really imporant
```

otherwise you wont get a reply

same as this:

```
ip route flush cache
```

I hope this helps someone out there!